# CodeIgniter form_validation and form_error - delete original error message

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter form_validation and

Everything works good except the original notification still appears in the top right.

Can anybody advise me how to delete the original notification?

I've inserted the PHP code into to view page.

```
<?php echo form_error('uname'); ?>
```

The form_error message appears the way I want but the original error message still appears in the top right, and I don't know how to delete that.

EDIT 01/08/19

Below is edited coding I've taken from the CI UserGuide.

Controller

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller
{
public function index()
{
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required', array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.'));
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
$this->load->view('myform');
}
else
{
$this->load->view('formsuccess');
}
}
}
```

View

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div></form>

</body>
</html>
```

If the above is loaded the result will be the Username Text Box in the top left corner, and the Password Text Box below it.

If the Submit button is clicked without any content in the text boxes the following notifications appear in the top left corner and above the Text Boxes.

You must provide a Username.

You must provide a Password.

However, if I change the view page to the following, the same notifications STILL APPEAR IN THE TOP LEFT CORNER, as well as next to the Text Boxes, so in effect each notification appears twice.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />
<?php echo form_error('password'); ?>

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div></form>

</body>
</html>
```

It is the notifications that still appear in the top left corner, that I want to delete.

I can't find any coding that positions the notifications so I guess that comes from somewhere within the CI system.

I can position the form_error notifications by using css coding.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, what's this *error message* and what's this *original message*, or maybe you could attach a picture of it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

```
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?> // When this is inserted.

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?> //This must be deleted.
```

Or put another way the coding above provides the notifications at the top right.